# Getting the property value of a page

Tags: episerver, episerver-7, episerver-6

I am very new to EpiServer and I want to develop a code for accessing property values of a page. I can access that using this code

```
PageData oPage = EPiServer.DataFactory.Instance.GetPage(new PageReference(30))
        string str = oPage.Property["RestURL"].ToString();
        TextBox1.Text = str;
```

but this is very hardcoded . So i want to access it dynamically like currentpage property values. but below code is giving error object reference is not set to an instabce of object.

```
public partial class Templates_Public_Pages_Scheduling : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //PageData oPage = EPiServer.DataFactory.Instance.GetPage(new PageReference());
        //PageData oPage = EPiServer.DataFactory.Instance.GetPage(new PageReference(;
        PageData oPage = EPiServer.DataFactory.Instance.CurrentPage;
        string str = oPage.Property["RestURL"].ToString();
        TextBox1.Text = str;

        //Property property = CurrentPage["propertyname"];  
    }
}
```

Please help me to overcome this.

Comment: Please specify one version of EPiServer, this is quite different in epi6 and 7

Comment: Your template page should probably inherit TemplatePage instead. That way you'll get the CurrentPage property (among other things) in your template to simplify accessing properties of the current page.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you dont have strongly typed classes for your pages. You can get the current page from HttpContext.

```
var currentPage = HttpContext.Current.Handler as PageData;
var property = currentPage.Property["RestURL"].ToString();
```